# How can one reliably prevent pedestrian access to a parking garage, but allow vehicular access?

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle, optimization

Consider a typical private parking garage for a condominium or apartment building.

There is currently a typical garage gate that opens and closes (slowly) to allow vehicles to pass safely through the gate.

What is the optimal method for preventing access into this garage by pedestrians/foot traffic, but ensuring the same safe entry/exit for vehicles?

The goal is to make sure people cannot enter/exit through the same gate that vehicles may enter/exit.

Practically implementable solutions only, please.  Cost need not be a factor.

Comment: When reading this question, I assumed I was looking at [Home Improvement SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This isn't really a puzzle, is it?

Comment: Even if this is a puzzle (which I feel is too broad), if someone actually comes up with a plausible solution, please tell me how Autobots fit into this situation...

Comment: Hire a security guard?

Comment: Only allow entry through a tunnel packed with angry bees?

Comment: @humn More of a bee-piquer than a bee-keeper you might say.

Comment: RIP anyone with a convertible or open windows ...

Comment: @APrough: Similar type of thinking applies to puzzles as to this question.  If anyone knows where I can get an Autobot, please tell me.

Comment: @Deusovi: It is a problem requiring creative thinking and ingenuity to generate a solution.  What is a puzzle?

Comment: @DeanRusmor It's a good engineering question, but it's too broad to be a puzzle. The goal is open-ended, and the term "optimal method" isn't defined. In general, a puzzle should have a finite number of solutions, if not a single solution. I suggest reading through [the tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Can't you just install a sign that says "pedestrians will be shot on sight"?

Comment: @IanMacDonald That would only work for pedestrians who are literate, risk-averse, and visible.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic here.  But, if you do find a place to ask it, you might want to clarify whether motorcycles are allowed.  How about bicycles?

Answer (score 3):

### Tunnel Car Wash

This [system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_wash#Automatic_car_wash) allows a car to safely pass through a series of industrial-grade cleaning equipment. Parts of a car wash typically include arrays that spray the vehicle with pressurized liquid, or large motorized brushes that wipe the car's exterior.

While this is safe for an automobile, it is a very bad method of entry or exit for a pedestrian.

If the garage is privately owned, and cost is not a factor, then the owner can hire a contractor. The contractor will then figure out a way to install the car wash system next to the gate.

Comment: Great answer.  This is the type of solution that could actually be useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a pressure gate.

We have this at my school, there is a white square in front of the gate which the vehicle drives onto. This is a pressure plate, and if the vehicle is on it it will identify the weight and the gate opens.

Even if many people stood on it, it would not open (yes we tried that).

Comment: Curious if this also excludes motorcycles/mopeds, assuming they're allowed in the garages as well.

Comment: @BradC one teacher has a motorcycle and it still works for him

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Beastly Gerbil.  One possible issue here is that a human could make it through the gate as a "tag along" to a vehicle already entering or exiting.

Answer (score 1):

> A metal detector ought to do the trick.

See:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_loop#Vehicle_detection

Comment: Er couldn't a citizen just walk through if they carried some metal on them?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The sensitivity can be adjusted. That precise scenario is described in the wiki tab too.